# Laravel update eloquent not updating the record

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel eloquent to update the record. The problem is the update method returns the integer equal to number of records should be updated but this update is not being reflected in database.

I inserted some records to check there is no database mismatch.

I am even using fillable method and defined every column into it.

Here is my code.

**Modal**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'ticket_no',
        'partner_id',
        'partner_user_name',
        'partner_user_email',
        'partner_user_contact',
        'contacted_for_id',
        'issue_type_id',
        'comm_mode_id',
        'opened_by_id',
        'assigned_to_id',
        'team_id',
        'priority_id',
        'opened_date',
        'tat_id',
        'resolved_date',
        'status_id',
        'description',
    ];
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $validators = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'assigned_to_id' => 'required',
            'team_id' => 'required',
            'resolve_date' => 'required',
            'status_id' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validators->fails()) {
            $data['result'] = false;
            $data['messages'] = $validators->errors()->first();

            return json_encode($data);
        }

        $assigned_to_id = $request->assigned_to_id;
        $team_id = $request->team_id;
        $resolve_date = $request->resolve_date;
        $status_id = $request->status_id;
        $description = $request->description;

        $ticket_row_id = $request->ticket_row_id;

        $updated = TICKET_TRACKER::where('id', $ticket_row_id)
            ->update(
                ['assigned_to_id' => $assigned_to_id],
                ['team_id' => $team_id],
                ['resolve_date' => $resolve_date],
                ['status_id' => $status_id],
                ['description' => $description]
            );
    }
```

I am not getting any error that's the most frustrated thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make your model to be updated change:

```php
 $updated = TICKET_TRACKER::where('id', $ticket_row_id)
            ->update(
                ['assigned_to_id' => $assigned_to_id],
                ['team_id' => $team_id],
                ['resolve_date' => $resolve_date],
                ['status_id' => $status_id],
                ['description' => $description]
            );
```

By:

```php
 $updated = TICKET_TRACKER::where('id', $ticket_row_id)
       ->update([
                 'assigned_to_id' => $assigned_to_id,
                 'team_id' => $team_id,
                 'resolve_date' => $resolve_date,
                 'status_id' => $status_id,
                 'description' => $description
          ]);
```

**In fact you need to have only one array with keys and values in order to view your model updated.**

**[EDIT 1]**

As said in the comments in Laravel you need to take care about **naming conventions**,

If the name of the model is TicketTracker, the name of the table should be plural. So it will be ticket_trackers.

or if you want to have a custom name for your table you can configure in your model the `$table` property as follows:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TicketTracker extends Model
{
    protected $table = "other_table_name"
}
```